# Copy without keeping reference

Tags: javascript, angular, object

So I have a variable called `elements` that hold a bunch of data. Let's say, for example, that this is it:

```
{
  name: "Jeff",
  age: "18",
  carList: [
    "car1": "...",
    "car2": "..."
  ],
  surname: "Matt"
}
```

I also have an empty array, at the start, declared this way:

```
public myArray: Model[] = [];
```

`Model` is just a class that contains the definition of the `elements`.

What I'm trying to achive is to have a copy of `elements` without keeping any reference to the original variable. but I'm missing something. Here's a pseudo-code that do the trick (almost) :

```
myfunction(){
  //Do stuff that change `car1` from `...` to `hello`
  myArray.push(Object.assign({}, this.elements));
}
```

And finnally a I have a function that print everything in the `myArray` variable:

```
function print(){
  this.myArray.forEach(el => {
    console.log(el);
  });
}
```

The problem is that every element of the array has the latest update done by me. 
So if `myFunction` was called several time doing something like:

- Change "Jeff" to "Jack"
- Change age "18" to "25"
- Change surname to "Seth"

what I see is three `log` showing this data:

```
{
  name: "Jeff",
  age: "25",
  carList: [
    "car1": "...",
    "car2": "..."
  ],
  surname: "Seth"
}
```

My question is: Why even using `Object.asign` it still keeping the reference to it's original object? I should keep the history of each modification, instead of having just the last edit in both of three edits I've made.

Thank you.

Comment: `Object.assign()` only performs a shallow copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));
```

It keeps no refrences, as you can observe in the snippet below:

```js
let element = { name: "Jeff", age: "18", carList: [ {"car1": "x"}, {"car2": "y"} ], surname: "Matt" };

let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));
result.name = "x";

console.log(result);
console.log("****element*****");
console.log(element);
```

Comment: yep, it's the fastest way, even faster than jquery .extend() method

Comment: Thank you, it works. but why?